# Matlab - Warn me about a Large Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, runtime, warnings, limit

I have been working with a few not particularly well designed or documented matlab scripts provided by my prof.  I am required to modify them in order to make them do what is required by the specification, but it is not immediately clear how large certain matrices will become.  I know if done properly the problems should not consume excessive resources, but more than a few times now I've had matlab hang trying to allocate huge blocks of memory.  I suspect this is because I multiplied a matrix I did not fully understand in the wrong order, resulting in a larger matrix, rather than for example a scalar.

Is there a way to have matlab prompt me if it finds it will need to allocate a matrix over a certain number of bytes?  That way while I'm debugging/maintaining code I'll have an opportunity to cancel, before it goes beserk.

Comment: No clue if Matlab provides these tools. Alternatively you could build wrapper functions around your operations that determine the dimensions and data types (size) of your scalars/vectors/matrices and then calculate the resulting dimensions and data type of your result in advance (which could then in turn be used to pre-allocate memory for your result when you do not abort as size gets to high).

Comment: You could muck around with the array size limit, either a hard limit or as a percentage of RAM. (Note this won't prompt you, it will just give you an error.)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html